# How does one show that Im$(2e^y\sin(x+iy))=(e^{2y}-1)\cos(x)$?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm thinking of rewriting $(x+iy)$ into Euler's form $re^{i\theta}$, but I can't see how it will help simplify the expression further.

Comment: You can use one of the definition of $\sin$, which is $\sin(z) = \dfrac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$ for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

We could try the addition formula.  I assume $x,y$ are real.
$$\begin{align}
\sin(x+iy) &= \sin(x)\cos(iy)+\cos(x)\sin(iy)
=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+i\cos(x)\sinh(y)
\\
\text{Im}\big(\sin(x+iy)\big) &= \cos(x)\sinh(y) = \cos(x)\frac{e^y-e^{-y}}{2}
\\
\text{Im}\big(2e^y\sin(x+iy)\big) &= \cos(x)e^y(e^y-e^{-y})=
\cos(x)(e^{2y}-1)
\end{align}$$